# How to group on referenced entities attributes in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, pymongo, sharding, mongodb-query

I am trying to build an event tracking system for my mobile apps. I am evaluating mongodb for my needs and I don't have any hands-on experience with NoSQL databases. I have read mongodb documentation thoroughly and have come up with following schema design for my needs.
1. Must have a horizontally scalable data store
2. Data store must execute group queries quickly in sharded environment
3. Must have extremely high write throughput

```
Collections:
Events:
{name:'<name>', happened_at:'<timestamp>', user : { imei: '<imei>', model_id: '<model_id>'}

Devices:
{model_id:'<model_id>', device_width:<width>, memory: '<memory>', cpu: '<cpu>'}
```

I do not want to store devices as embedded document with in events.user to save storage space in my fastest growing collection i.e. events. Devices collection is not going to grow much and must be having records not more than 30k. While events collection is going to have few million documents added every day.

My data growth needs a sharded environment and we shall care about that from day 1 and hence not use anything which doesn't work in sharded system. 
e.g. Group functions don't work with shards, we shall always write mongo M/R commands for such needs.

Problem: What is the best way to get all user who did a particular event(name='abc happened') on devices, having device_width<300.
My solution: Find all models having device_width<300 and use result for filtering events documents on such models.

Problem: Return count of users for which a particular event(name='abc happened') on devices, grouped against cpu of device
My solution: Get count of users for given event, grouped by model_ids(<30k records, I know). Further group with model_id related cpu and return final result.

Please let me know if I am doing it the right way. If not, what is the right way to do it at scale?

EDIT: Please also point out if there is any possible caveat like indexes might not get used to maximum effect with map/reduce.

Comment: Your solutions seem fine, assuming you've added indexes for the fields you're planning to search on. You shouldn't need to use MapReduce generally. Look to the aggregation pipeline if a standard `find` doesn't meet your needs (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/).

Comment: you should absolutely NOT use mapreduce but instead use aggregation framework - it will be faster and simpler in many ways.

Comment: Thank You Asya and WiredPrairie, much help. Aggregation framework is serving my need and I will use that only as it's better.